# Jenkins restoring Nuget packages - Proxy not working

Tags: jenkins, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I've got a Jenkins server up and running and a single job configured.  It's behind a proxy and I've configured the proxy settings in the relevant Nuget.config file.

When the job runs it seems that the entries for the proxy settings are ignored and I get a series of errors for each package that nuget tries to restore:

```
The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
```

If I copy the command line that Jenkins fires off to launch Nuget and paste it into a command prompt window the restore operation works perfectly.

I'm I missing something to get nuget package restores working behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I needed to also set the Jenkins service to run under a domain account as well as having the config file setup with the proxy login details.